# Require and Validate input Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a Flow with a screen where the user have inputs for Account and Contacts.

The user should fill all Account fields, so all those fields are required. But he may want it or not to create a contact. So those fields are not required.

However when filling a field like "FirstName" I want to have a validation so that the other fields like "LastName", "Email" or "Phone" should also be required

These are my thoughs about this topic:

### **Decision Element**

The way I'm doing is performing a decision element after the screen to validate that condition

- Currently I'm redirecting to same screen and show a message -> This is not a bad option.
- But due to also implementing a BACK option, I need to redirect to a specific Error Screen that just show the message so the user click on BACK and go to input screen. (If redirecting to same screen, a BACK will be to same screen before the validation)
  Due to this, I'm trying to perform the validations without exiting the screen

### **Validate Field input**

I can add a validation like: AND( ISBLANK(FirstName) , ISBLANK(LastName) ,..... ) . That could work if all the inputs here like Text. When filling 1 it will throw an error on that field because the others are empty.
However I have a picklist field that doesn't have a validate input, and also have an Email, a Phone input and other text that already have a pattern validation

### **Create a LWC/Aura Component with the fields and have validation on JS**

Should not be necessary to create a whole component just for this :/

### Create a LWC/Aura Component to show error messages

Different from the previous point, my intention here was to have a component that received a custom validation formula and display custom error message. 
Again is a custom component but could be reused on other screens or having multiple on same screen for different validations. I could even try to reuse on my existing Custom Footer
My doubts was exactly how to implement it and if it would be possible to receive something like a dynamic String that would the validation to perform: "{!FirstName} != null && ...'. Or if it could be some event on component.



As anyone else got the same problem?

Comment: Should this validation requirement be enforced across all Contact creation efforts or for this screen flow only?

Comment: It should occur only for this Screen Only.